# Symfony and Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony1, xmlhttprequest, symfony-1.4

This is my first time dabbling with Ajax in a Symfony context, and I am possibly a little confused by how the code must be organized.

Let's say my ajax call looks like this:

```
$.getJSON('module/getMeSomeJSONThroughAjax', function(data) {console.log(data); } )
```

and in my module/actions folder, the actions.class.php file has a method:

```
public function getMeSomeJSONThroughAjax()
{
   // do something
   return $jsonEncodedString;
}
```

Keep in mind, that I am `not creating a template for the above method`, hence I don't have the **execute** prefix as most other actions would. Simply coz I don't think creating a template is a case of overkill for fetching only JSON data for an AJAX HTTP request.

However, upon the event taking place in my browser that triggers the Ajax call, my console logs the following:

```
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
> (Not Found)
> http://localhost:8080/customerview_dev.php/flashcard/getMeSomeJSONThroughAjax
```

I am perceiving this to be a routing issue. A possible way to simply get rid of the problem would be to create a template for the above and rename the Action to `executeGetMeSomeJsonThroughAjax()`. But like I mentioned, this IMHO is overkill and there has to be a more aesthetically and proper way of getting this done.

What do you Symfonians do for making Ajax calls ?

Comment: Hint: stick with Symfony2 if you don't have legacy issues.

Comment: seriously? you want me to move to Symfony 2 because of an ajax jquery issue...ajax works fine in all versions of symfony with a lot of websites in production

Comment: Symfony 2 is plain better [by def], if you need to start a work from scratch there is no sense in using an outdated framework. If you need to maintain legacy code, of course you have to stick with the older version, as I clearly stated.

Comment: i flagged your comment because it is irrelevant to my question, this is a question on how to deal with Ajax in a Symfony 1.4 context, I appreciate your concern in recommending a better framework to me, but  that just does not address this question, please read stackoverflow rules for this, thanks

Comment: To the downvoter : Can you please leave a comment as to why you downvoted my question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need the execute prefix, even if you don't have a template.
You can set the templates to None if you want, or:

```
return $this->renderText($jsonEncodeString);
```

should work too.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of this is:

Controller:

```
namespace something;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller; 
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class AjaxController extends Controller {
    public function doSometingInAjaxAction()
    {
        $request        = $this->getRequest();
        $id             = $request->get('id');    
        $em             = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $object         = $em->getRepository('Bundle:Bundle')->find($id);
        $objectJson     = json_encode($object);        
        return new Response($modelosJson);        
    } }
```

The view:

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){

     //...

     $.ajax({
        url: '{{ path('admin_ajax_ajax') }}', 
        data: id,
        success: function (response) 
        {    
         //someting
         }                
     });
     });


</script>
```

The Router

```
admin_ajax_ajx:
    path:  /a/supercool/path//
    defaults: { _controller: Bundle:Ajax:doSometingInAjax }
```

This is the base and work for me